# How to rbind in for loop using string as object name

Tags: r, rbind

I have some data that I want to sort according to a column within the row

which looks like this:

```
   Rk         Player Pos Age  Tm  G   MP  PER   TS. X3PAr
1 492   Tyler Zeller   C  25 BOS 82 1731 18.9 0.594 0.000
2 491    Cody Zeller   C  22 CHO 62 1487 14.1 0.530 0.003
3 490 Thaddeus Young  PF  26 TOT 76 2434 15.7 0.507 0.119
4 490 Thaddeus Young  PF  26 MIN 48 1605 15.0 0.491 0.101
5 490 Thaddeus Young  PF  26 BRK 28  829 17.1 0.539 0.153
6 489     Nick Young  SG  29 LAL 42 1000 14.2 0.520 0.473
```

What Im trying to do is, as I iterate through the row, assign the row to a dataframe named after the 'Tm' (team) value. So during the first iteration if it does not exist, create the dataframe named `BOS`. The next time it sees a row with `Tm` column equal to `BOS` assign the row to the dataframe `BOS`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(allPlayers)){

  row <- allPlayers[i,]
  teamName <- toString(allPlayers[i,'Tm'])


    if(!exists(teamName)){

        assign(teamName,data.frame())
      }
  assign(teamName,rbind(teamName,row))
}
```

But the only value that I get in each dataframe is the row from the last iteration for that team.

What I want would be multiple dataframes with all of their according players like so

```
BOS
492 Tyler Zeller    C   25  BOS 82  1731    18.9    0.594   0
488 James Young SG  19  BOS 31  332 8.5 0.457   0.647
485 Brandan Wright  PF  27  BOS 8   86  15  0.571   0

ATL
431 Jeff Teague PG  26  ATL 73  2228    20.6    0.566   0.233
404 Thabo Sefolosha SF  30  ATL 52  976 13.8    0.506   0.313
403 Mike Scott  PF  26  ATL 68  1123    15.1    0.543   0.424
401 Dennis Schroder PG  21  ATL 77  1516    15.7    0.516   0.223
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `teams <- split(allPlayers, allPlayers$Tm)`. This will return a list where each list element is the data frame with all players from a particular team. As an added bonus, you won't pollute your namespace with a bunch of team-specific variables -- they are all stored in the returned list. You can access the team-specific data frame with the double square bracket notation, e.g. `teams[["BOS"]]`.

Comment: @josliber thats great! It worked like a charm. If you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: This has been covered before in previous questions, so I've marked this question as a duplicate of one of those previous questions.